# How to print a `QString` using `QDebug`?

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, qtbluetooth

I need to write a terminal application that lists the available bluetooth devices nearby, here is my attempt at it:

```
void findDevice()
{
   QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;
    QString localDeviceName;
    localDeviceName= localDevice.name();
    QDebug << localDeviceName;

}
```

The first step I took is to print my own device name then once done that I could move on into retrieving a list of  device and print them the same way. However I constantly keep getting the error:

`expected unqualified-id`

```
`QDebug << localDeviceName;
       ^
```

and dont know what seems to be the problem here.

Comment: what qt version are you using?

Comment: do you have in you .pro file CONFIG += console ?. if not, add and rebuild your project

Answer (score 5):

You need to :

```
qDebug() << localDeviceName;
```

Comment: have you `#included <QDebug>`?

Comment: Correction, the program crashes as soon as it runs, meaning i get runtime error

Comment: Have you tried debugging? On which line does your application crash?